# Computing basic conditional probability.

Tags: probability

A box contains three coins: two regular coins and one fake two-headed coin.
You pick a coin at random and toss it, and get heads. What is the probability that it is the two-headed coin?
I hope you can help me.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let A be the event that you choose the two-headed coin, and this is clear $P(H \mid A)=1$.And, you are interested in finding $P(A\mid H)$.By using the Bayes rule
$P(A\mid H)$=$\frac{P(H \mid A).P(A)}{P(H)}=\frac{1.1/3}{2/3}=\frac{1}{2}.$

Answer (score 1):

Among the three coins there are $4$ heads, each with an equal probability of being observed.  Of these $4$ heads, $2$ of them belong to the fake coin.  So if you observe a head, the probability it belongs to the fake coin is $2/4$.